# Selenium webdriver doesn't click on save button in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

My project is in mvc and I want to test it using selenium web driver.
Some button clicks work properly. But when I navigate to different page saying continue on that page Save button doesn't work.

Below is my code

```
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("BtnAddNew")).Click();

        IWebElement cat = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Cat"));
        cat.SendKeys("Single-family house");

        IWebElement ext_id = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ExternalId"));
        ext_id.SendKeys("SAR_47");

        IWebElement zip = driver.FindElement(By.Id("AddressZipTown"));
        zip.SendKeys("1205 Genève");

        IWebElement street = driver.FindElement(By.Id("AddressStreet"));
        street.SendKeys("Tramstrasse 10");

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnContinue")).Click();

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSave")).Click();

        driver.Quit();
```

Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: Looks like you need to sync using waits, like after clicking on to go to the next page, you shall wait for some time or wait for some element to appear before you want to click on it. If that does not work, please pass more info like what error you are getting.

Comment: I am getting error "no such element exception". It works properly in IE. I tried using all types of elements finder but it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by checking the DOM for a certain amount of time to try to find your WebElement. You can use Implicit or Explicit Waits.

Doc:

> http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits
>   http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits